# Crash course on photography for 3d rendering texture

Tags: 3d, texture

I'm looking for a place where to find informations about specifically photography to make 3D render textures: from simple texture to environmental mapping.

Does anyone can give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

For **environmental mapping** take a look on this ugly notes I did sometime ago. I will update them later. http://www.otake.com.mx/Apuntes/Imagen/EnviromentMaps/

For **simple textures** you need to take the photo of the texture with the most uniform difuse ligth you can. You can make a light tent for example.

This is to isolate the difuse map from shadows that you will add later in the rendering.

You can make a modified black and white version for some bump maps.